# When webpage refreshes, does not default focus to the top of the SharePoint page

Tags: html, sharepoint, coldfusion, focus

I have a registration page written in ColdFusion5, which is nested within a SharePoint 2010 page.
When I click the submit button on the registration, the registration page goes to the confirmation page as required, but I need the SharePoint page to be scrolled to the very top.

I have researched online and tried:

Adding the #top to the registration page via the form tag:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return NonMemberValidateForm2()" action="processRegistration.cfm#top">
```

Adding location.href='#top' to the onload function of the confirmation page:

```
<body onload="location.href='#top'">
```

However, none of these work.  Any ideas?

Edit:
I have a web part viewer on my SharePoint page. Its a large part, so I have to scroll down on the actual SharePoint page to view the whole thing (I already disabled the scrollbars on the web part).  When I am scrolled down towards the bottom of the SharePoint page, I click a button in the viewer.  This refreshes the page in the viewer, however I am still located at the bottom of the SharePoint page.  I want to be able to attach some code to that button that makes the outside SharePoint page be scrolled all the way to the top.

Comment: Did you add the referenced anchor to the top of your page (or does it already exist)?  `<a name="top"></a>`.  You might also try [this tip from Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/822-Using-BODY-ID-As-A-Back-To-Top-Page-Anchor.htm).  Are all browsers behaving the same way or is this issue specific to one?

Comment: I have that code right after my <body> tag... still nothing

Comment: Is there other JavaScript in the page that is enforcing focus on another element?

Comment: No. Focus is only set when validation errors occur.

Comment: Are all browsers behaving the same way?  There must be something else in play here.  The default behavior when requesting a new page is to load the page from the top.  Is the form submitting to a new page or is it calling itself?

Comment: It is acting the same in IE and Chrome.  It is a webpage within a SharePoint page... I don't know if there is something different we need to do because of that.

Comment: the problem with scrolling in SharePoint is that hides default scroll and implements custom one. Check this post: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26539/scroll-position-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: Please see my edit above... I guess I didn't explain the problem thoroughly enough before, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As Marek pointed out in his comment, SharePoint 2010 basically "kills" anchor support on pages. This issue is caused by the specific implementation Microsoft chose to follow for supporting the ribbon UI display and keeping it fixed on top of the page.

Explaining all the code here would be to long, but basically it boils down to the body tag of the page beging marked with "scroll=no"

```
<body scroll="no">
```

This actually disable scrolling while the page loads. A javascript function by the name of FixRibbonAndWorkspaceDimensions is then executed to add "overflow" and scrolling support to the page.

That said, if you want to use anchors you will have to edit your master page to change the aforementioned code. If you decide to follow this road, your best guess would be to try to re-implement the ribbon to use position:fixed instead of a javascript function to manage positioning.

Actually, someone already tried this. Have a look at this blog post from Kyle. It may help you if you decide to try to fix the page layout: [SharePoint 2010 Scrolling](http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-scrolling/).

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I want to keep the SharePoint scrollbars, but when I refresh a web page inside of a web part viewer, I want the SharePoint page to scroll to the top automatically.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be a different (still related) problem. Let me think if anything comes to mind, I seem to recall having a similar problem in the past.